# Get total sum of keys in json string with vanilla js

Tags: javascript, json

I have this object

```
{
    'company': [{
        'you': 619000,
        'group': 47918
    }],
    'savings': [{
        'you': 1805000,
        'group': 278172
    }],
    'carBoat': [{
        'you': 269000,
        'group': 101666
    }],
    'pension': [{
        'you': 2220000,
        'group': 1023814
    }],
    'home': [{
        'you': 3600000,
        'group': 2114516
    }]
```

}

I am trying to figure out an efficient way to get the total sum of all the "you" and all the "group", But I struggle a bit to find it.

I want to avoid doing something like

```
company.you + savings.you + carBoat.you + pension.you + home.you
```

and have it in a more dynamic way.

Comment: Do you want the total sum of you and group to be in one result or as two separate results? Also, is there a reason for your object's values being arrays?

Comment: So your question basically boils down to, how can I loop over the object properties without knowing their names (or number)? That should be something you should be able to research quite easily.

Comment: Loop over them?

Comment: total sum of all  the "you" and all the "group" but your example sums only the you, what is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Object iterators like [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const ob = {
    'company': [{
        'you': 619000,
        'group': 47918
    }],
    'savings': [{
        'you': 1805000,
        'group': 278172
    }],
    'carBoat': [{
        'you': 269000,
        'group': 101666
    }],
    'pension': [{
        'you': 2220000,
        'group': 1023814
    }],
    'home': [{
        'you': 3600000,
        'group': 2114516
    }]
};

const youTot = Object.values(ob).reduce((a,v) => a += v[0].you, 0);
console.log(youTot)
```

Your initial data has possibly a **redundant** unnecessary Array `[]` **holding only one Object**. If that's not a mistake, and you don't only want to retrieve the one `[0]`th entry - but multiple Arrayvalues from objects - and reduce them too, than you could loop as well that array:

```js
const ob = {
  'company': [{
      'you': 1,
      'group': 0
    },
    {
      'you': 2,
      'group': 0
    }
  ],
  'savings': [{
    'you': 4,
    'group': 0
  }],
};

const youTot = Object.values(ob).reduce((a, v) => a += v.reduce((a, ob) => a+= ob.you, 0), 0);
console.log(youTot);    // 7
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reduce()`. I use inside of reduce an second reduce if for example there would be more then 1 element in the array

```js
let json = {
    'company': [{
        'you': 619000,
        'group': 47918
    }],
    'savings': [{
        'you': 1805000,
        'group': 278172
    }],
    'carBoat': [{
        'you': 269000,
        'group': 101666
    }],
    'pension': [{
        'you': 2220000,
        'group': 1023814
    }],
    'home': [{
        'you': 3600000,
        'group': 2114516
    }]
}

let result = Object.values(json).reduce((a, v) => {
   let yous = v.reduce((a,v) => a + v.you,0);
   let groups = v.reduce((a,v) => a + v.group,0)
   a.you += yous;
   a.group += groups;
   return a;
}, {you: 0, group: 0})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {
    'company': [{
        'you': 619000,
        'group': 47918
    }],
    'savings': [{
        'you': 1805000,
        'group': 278172
    }],
    'carBoat': [{
        'you': 269000,
        'group': 101666
    }],
    'pension': [{
        'you': 2220000,
        'group': 1023814
    }],
    'home': [{
        'you': 3600000,
        'group': 2114516
    }]
};

let result = Object.values(obj).reduce((acc,curr) => {
    acc.you += curr[0].you;
    acc.group += curr[0].group;
    return acc;
}, {you:0, group: 0});
console.log(result)
```